# jQuery FadeIn nested Images one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein

Hi JQuery Masters i need some help from you, i have some div's

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="image-div">
         <img src="img" />
    </div>
</div>
```

<div class="column">
    <div class="image-div">
        <img src="img" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="image-div">
         <img src="img" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="image-div">
        <img src="img" />
    </div>
</div>

with images (images are hide via css) in a document and i want to fadeIn images in div,s 1 after 1 with 500ms delay and when all images are fadeIn callback alert completed please do this with little jQuery code Thanks

Comment: nearly exact duplicate of [Jquery image fadein delay by X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274832/jquery-image-fadein-delay-by-x)

Comment: @Groovetrain there is only one css class apply to my all div,s, this the difference between

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div.image-div").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6jn/3/

Comment: delay() looks like a useful function to use, no need for callbacks

Comment: @Hussein Thanks its working great for me with some modifications like i want to fadein images not div,s and a callback for add a class .done to div when it,s image is faded in it

Comment: @anjum To fade in images and not divs, just replace the selector with `$("div.image-div img")`. You can place your callback in the fadeIn function like `fadeIn(300, function(){...})`. If you need anything else beyond what was asked in the question, please start another question.

Comment: @Hussein i have solved this but i want to addClass done to each div that has image fadin  http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6jn/11/

Comment: @anjum, you are already adding the class. I gave the `done` class a blue border property so you can see it. http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6jn/13/

Comment: @Hussein when i reload my site page and when first image is fadein class done added to all divs i want to add class each div

Comment: @Hussein i solved this `$(".image-div img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(500, function() {
        $('.image-div').eq(index).addClass('done');
          });
});` **check out working example here http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6jn/18/**

Comment: Uh ok, i didn't know what you were referring to. Glad it worked for you.